# Jquery UI tabe not working with JScrollPane after the window is resized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, jscrollpane

I am working on an html video gallery using Jquery, fancybox, jScrollPane and Jquery Ui tabs.
The gallery is separated into tabs using jquery ui, each tab then hosts a jScrollPane. In order to keep the data resizing when the window is re-sized a function was written to change the css of the containers and reinitialize the jscrollpanes.
The code for the jquery is as follows:

```
$('.thumbNails').jScrollPane({});
$('.Captions').jScrollPane();
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.video__gallery_container').css('width',$(window).width()-40);
    $('.thumbNails').css('width','95%');
    $('.Captions').css('width','95%');
    $('.thumbNails').jScrollPane().reinitialize();
    $('.Captions').jScrollPane().reinitialize();
});
```

The html:
    
    
    
        
        
        Video Gallery

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/video_gallery_ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="tabs" class="video_gallery_container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="tab">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2" class="tab">Pilots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3" class="tab">Pilots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4" class="tab">145 Repair Station</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5" class="tab">Supply</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" class="thumbNails">
                         <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip" class="videoLink" videowidth="800" videoheight="450" videofile="cycling_large"  videocaption="Caption for cycling_large goes here" ></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="640" videoheight="360" videofile="ocean_medium" videocaption="Caption for ocean_medium goes here" ></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="400" videoheight="250" videofile="winecountry_part1" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part1 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="640" videoheight="402"  videofile="winecountry_part2" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part2 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="860" videoheight="540" videofile="winecountry_part3" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part3 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="300" videoheight="168" videofile="cycling_small"  videocaption="Caption for cycling_small goes here" ></a>
                         <div class="clear_both"></div></div>

        <div id="tabs-2" class="thumbNails">
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="860" videoheight="540" videofile="winecountry_part3" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part3 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="300" videoheight="168" videofile="cycling_small"  videocaption="Caption for cycling_small goes here" ></a>
                         <div class="clear_both"></div></div>
        <div id="tabs-3" class="thumbNails">
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="800" videoheight="450" videofile="cycling_large"  videocaption="Caption for cycling_large goes here" ></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="640" videoheight="360" videofile="ocean_medium" videocaption="Caption for ocean_medium goes here" ></a>
                         <div class="clear_both"></div></div>
        <div id="tabs-4" class="thumbNails">
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="400" videoheight="250" videofile="winecountry_part1" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part1 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="640" videoheight="402"  videofile="winecountry_part2" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part2 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="860" videoheight="540" videofile="winecountry_part3" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part3 goes here"></a>
                         <div class="clear_both"></div></div>
        <div id="tabs-5" class="thumbNails">
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="860" videoheight="540" videofile="winecountry_part3" videocaption="Caption for winecountry_part3 goes here"></a>
                         <a class="videoLink" videowidth="300" videoheight="168" videofile="cycling_small"  videocaption="Caption for cycling_small goes here" ></a>
                         <div class="clear_both"></div></div>
    <div class="Captions"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Hidden DIV container for video overlay code -->
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="videoPlayer"></div>
    </div>
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster-->
<script src="includes/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="includes/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/css/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // Tabs
    $('#tabs').tabs();

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now to the heart of the problem, the code runs perfect until the window is resized, after the resized if a tab is selected the contents of the tab are not displayed, however if the window is subsequently resized the content will appear. Also after resizing if another tab is selected you can return the tab that was loaded when the resized was done and it still has the content. I have tried manually triggering the resize event with code such as 
    $('.tab').live('click',function(){ $(this).trigger('resize'); };
Thanks for any help.